# to remove tr by searching exact text in td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in which I have list of name.

Now I want to delete it by jquery on basis on its text.

`$(addrow + " td:contains(" + foodname + ")").parent('tr').next("tr").remove();`

I have this which works fine but it have a flaw.

For eg for removing 'xyz',

Case 1:  td with text such as xyz,abc,poi etc. ------> it works fine

Case 2:  td with text such as xyz,abxyzc,poi etc. ------> removes xyz and xyzabc as well

Is there a direct way to check exact and not contains in td by jquery?

Thank you!

Comment: What you actually want to delete the row which contains the `td` text or row next to it?
Also, please post your `Html` structure it will help to know your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

match your td text value with `text()`

Try below code -

If you want to delete `tr` which is next to that 'tr' in which `td` matches with the text.

```
$(addrow).find('td').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == foodname){
        $(this).parent('tr').next("tr").remove();
    }
});
```

Or you just want to delete the `tr` whose `td` matches with the text.

```
$(addrow).find('td').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == foodname){
        $(this).parent('tr').remove(); // don't use next() here
    }
});
```

Comment: Although I have used a different method, but this seems nice and simple! Thanks!